# How to Count the number of AD Groups a user a member of

Tags: active-directory, powershell, count

I've tried several ways of doing this, however I've found the below has been the best so far, which I found via another website. It works really well, however I now require to have the script get the number of AD Groups each user is a member of on another Domain.

Here is the working script:

```
# Either create an array of target users or import via a file
$colUser = (get-content "C:\TR\List.txt")    
 
# Create a report array object
$UserReport = @()
 
foreach ($objUser in $colUser) {
    # Cycle through our target users
    $ErrorFlag = $false
    
    Try {
        # Attempt to enumerate and count the target users group membership
        $count = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $objUser | measure | select -expand count
    } Catch {
        # If we get an error - capture it and skip adding this user to the report
        write-host "Error: $_"
        $ErrorFlag = $true
    }
     
    If (!$ErrorFlag) {
        # When we don't have an error - add the user details to a hash object
        $UserHash = @{
                Username        = $objUser
                Groupcount      = $count
        }
 
        # Create a new object using our hash object
        $objUserInfo = New-Object PSObject -Property $UserHash
        # Add the new object to the reporting array
        $UserReport += $objUserInfo
    }
}
# Output our report object sorted by descending group membership numbers
$UserReport | sort -desc Groupcount | export-csv C:\TR\ExportCount.csv
```

I've tried adding

```
Get-ADDomain -Server 'DC.Server'
```

in various places, however it tends to either break the script, or the script just doesn't look for accounts in the new domain.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are all the users on `C:\TR\List.txt` on the same Domain or are they on different Domains?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Get-AdUser -filter "*" -Properties memberof |
  Select SamAccountName,@{n="NumberOfGroups";e={$_.memberof.count}} |
  Where-Object { $_.NumberOfGroups -gt 0 } |
  Export-CSV C:\TR\ExportCount.csv
```

For a different domain than the one you are currently using:

```
Get-AdUser -Server whatever.example.com `
  -Credential (Get-Credential) -filter "*" `
  -Properties memberof
```

The rest stays the same.

To get only users listed in a file:

```
Get-Content "C:\TR\List.txt" | Get-AdUser #... rest of the above
```

<sub>This assumes that the file contains one username per line.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, where do I input this?

Comment: In a PowerShell window, just like your script.

Comment: I meant in the script, which line should I add it into please?

Comment: This is not meant to be added to your script. It's basically a replacement. A single command that does everything your script does, but much less complicated.

Comment: There's too many accounts in the domain. I'm trying to make it so it only grabs the accounts listed in the text file. Can that be done?

Comment: Sure. See the latest edit.

Comment: Sorry I'm now getting an error. Please see the updated edit.

Comment: Please don't edit answers with your own stuff. This is not a discussion forum, it's a QA site. If you encounter a new problem, ask a new question for it.